# Counting iterations of 1 in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal is to count iterations of 1 in an array.
I have this code:

```
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
if(array[i] === 1)
count++;
}

console.log(count);
```

Right now, it logs 5, but including "10" it should log 6, since "10" also contains a 1. What code can I use for this?

Comment: Should you count twice for `11`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` method in combination with `length` property in order to write a more **cleaner** solution.

Also, use `join` and `split` methods in order to achieve your requirement.

```js
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];
console.log(array.join('').split('').filter(a=>a==1).length);
```

or using `reduce` method.

```js
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];
console.log(array.join('').split('').reduce((c,i)=> i==1 ? c+1 :c).length);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var count = array.toString().split('1').length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert every item to string, and then check if `1` belongs to that number or not.

So for number 10, the string is `'10'` and then `'10'.indexOf('1')` equals to `0`. So every time `1` is found within the string, you increment the counter.

```js
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  if (array[i].toString().indexOf('1') >= 0)
    count++;
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: `11` instead of `10` will log again `6`

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your numbers into digits and iterate over each digit (which is a character) and compare with it. Use [**Object#toString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to parse the number into the `string`, split into characters by [**String#split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and using [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterate over characters and do the same comparison there.

```js
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];
var count = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {

   var numberAsString = array[i].toString();

   numberAsString.split('').forEach(char => {
      if(char === '1') {
        count++
      }
   });
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert each number to a string and use `indexOf`

```js
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];
var count = array.reduce(function(p,c){
    if(c.toString().indexOf("1")>-1)
        p++;
    return p;
},0);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array items to a string and count using [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression:

```js
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];

// the || [] is a fallback in case there is no 1, and match returns null
var result = (array.join('').match(/1/g) || []).length;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check every character of the joined string.

```js
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1],
    count = 0,
    i,
    temp = array.join('');

for (i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
    if (temp[i] === '1') {
        count++;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [10, 3, 22, 40, 1, 40, 1, 22, 1, 0, 3, 53, 1, 1];
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
    if( array[i] === 1 || array[i].toString().includes("1") )
    count++;
}
console.log( count );
```